# Preventing Overflow of Content when using CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

:

I have a main container with 2 divs(let's call them left and right) nested in it. A CSS Grid is applied to the main container giving it 2 columns, both of equal sizes(1fr).

Normally, a CSS Grid is supposed to grow and shrink depending on the amount of size available, but when I add content into "" and "", it stops the Grid from shrinking at a certain point and content overflows.

[Content overflowing a CSS Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9tEV.png)
    ?

To combat this, I used relative units when specifying the size and width of all individual elements in "" and "", so that the elements can shrink and grow according to the size allocated but I still face the problem described above.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
  background-color: hsl(185, 41%, 84%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.logo {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}

main {
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 3rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1.2rem;
  padding: 2em;
}


/*Left main*/

label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #5E7A7D;
}

input {
  border: none;
  background-color: #F3F9FA;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #00474B;
  padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
  width: 90%
}

.btn-cntr {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 0.3fr 0.3fr/ 0.2fr 0.2fr 0.2fr;
  gap: 10px;
}

button {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.5em 0.9em;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: white;
}

.custom {
  background-color: #F3F9FA;
  color: #547878;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}


/*Right main*/

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 1.2rem;
  padding-left: 1em;
  background-color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.small-text {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #7F9D9F;
}

.amount {
  color: hsl(172, 67%, 45%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 0px;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.reset-btn {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
  background-color: hsl(172, 67%, 45%);
}

.total-sum {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="./images/logo.svg" class="logo" alt="logo: word splitter">
  <main>
    <section class="left">
      <label for="Bill">Bill</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="Bill" placeholder="$">

      <p>Select Tip %</p>
      <div class="btn-cntr">
        <button class="percentage">5%</button>
        <button class="percentage">10%</button>
        <button class="percentage">15%</button>
        <button class="percentage">25%</button>
        <button class="percentage">50%</button>
        <button class="percentage custom">Custom</button>
      </div>

      <label for="n-pple">Number of People</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="n-pple" placeholder="">
    </section>

    <section class="right">
      <div class="total-sum">
        <p>Tip Amount / person</p>
        <p class="amount">Total </p>
      </div>

      <div class="total-sum">
        <p>Total / person</p>
        <p class="amount"> TotalS</p>
      </div>
      <button class="reset-btn">Reset</button>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Basically, the grid cell can't shrink narrower than is content, so once its the width of the word "totals", that's it. My recommendation would be to make the `btn-cntr` div on the other side more responsive, removing `width: 90%` on the buttons and instead using something like `grid-template:  0.3fr 0.3fr/ repeat(auto-fit, 140px);`. That whole left side could squeeze down a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

A few small adjustments will get you going. The main issue is that you need the content in your columns to be responsive. But at some point you'll also need to switch from two columns to a single column.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
  background-color: hsl(185, 41%, 84%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.logo {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}

main {
  width: 70%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  gap: 2em 3em;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1.2rem;
  padding: 2em;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  }
}

/*Left main*/

label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #5E7A7D;
}

input {
  border: none;
  background-color: #F3F9FA;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #00474B;
  padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
  width: 90%
}

.btn-cntr {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

button {
  min-width: 4em;
  background-color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.5em 0.9em;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: white;
}

.custom {
  background-color: #F3F9FA;
  color: #547878;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}


/*Right main*/

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.small-text {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #7F9D9F;
}

.amount {
  color: hsl(172, 67%, 45%);
  font-size: clamp(1em, 3vw, 2em);
  margin: 0px;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.reset-btn {
  width: 6em;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
  background-color: hsl(172, 67%, 45%);
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.total-sum {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0 2em;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="./images/logo.svg" class="logo" alt="logo: word splitter">
  <main>
    <section class="left">
      <label for="Bill">Bill</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="Bill" placeholder="$">

      <p>Select Tip %</p>
      <div class="btn-cntr">
        <button class="percentage">5%</button>
        <button class="percentage">10%</button>
        <button class="percentage">15%</button>
        <button class="percentage">25%</button>
        <button class="percentage">50%</button>
        <button class="percentage custom">Custom</button>
      </div>

      <label for="n-pple">Number of People</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="n-pple" placeholder="">
    </section>

    <section class="right">
      <div class="total-sum">
        <p>Tip Amount / person</p>
        <p class="amount">Total $</p>
      </div>

      <div class="total-sum">
        <p>Total / person</p>
        <p class="amount"> Total $</p>
      </div>
      <button class="reset-btn">Reset</button>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```